# Having trouble with getting C++ program to run correctly

Tags: c++

I am still fairly new to programming so my code is in no way perfect. I am having trouble getting my program to run correctly and I am honestly suck on what needs to be fixed, although I do know the ReadArtGalleryData part is not written correctly. I have attached a picture of what the output is supposed to look like. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

// global variables
struct ARTWORK
{
    string Name;        // artist name
    string Title;       // painting title
    string Medium;      // material used
    string Room;        // name of room its held in
    double Price;       // price of painting
    double Height;      // height of painting
    double Width;       // width of painting
};

const int NUMPIECES = 50;
ARTWORK GalleryOfArt[NUMPIECES];        // an array GalleryOfArt of structs ArtWork, of size 50

int ReadArtGalleryData();       // reads in the gallery inventory for each painting from the file SimpleArtGalleyDimen.txt
int PrintMenu();               // displays a menu of different search fields by which the user can search the gallery 
void PrintEntry(int);         // function to print details of art found in the gallery
void ActionOnChoice(int choice, int count);      // branching function depending on the choice made by the user
void FindString(int count, int choice, string searchStr);       // function used to search the gallery inventory using the following fields - artist name, painting title, medium used, room displayed in
void FindNumber(int choice, float searchNumber);        // function used to search the gallery inventory using either the price, height, width, or value


int main()
{

int fileread = ReadArtGalleryData();
int choice = PrintMenu();
ActionOnChoice(choice, fileread);

return 0;
}


int ReadArtGalleryData()
{
    int i = 0;
    fstream infile;
    infile.open("SimpleArtGalleryDimen.txt");

}

int PrintMenu()
{
    int fileread;
    cout << "1. Print Entry" << endl;
    cout << "2. Find String" << endl;
    cout << "3. Find Number" << endl;
    cin >> fileread;
    return fileread;
}

void PrintEntry(int fileread)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < fileread; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(15);
        cout << GalleryOfArt[i].Name << endl;
        cout << setw(15);
        cout << GalleryOfArt[i].Title << endl;
        cout << setw(15);
        cout << GalleryOfArt[i].Medium << endl;
        cout << setw(15);
        cout << GalleryOfArt[i].Room << endl;
        cout << setw(15);
        cout << GalleryOfArt[i].Price << endl;
        cout << setw(15);
        cout << GalleryOfArt[i].Height << endl;
        cout << setw(15);
        cout << GalleryOfArt[i].Width << endl;
    }

}

void ActionOnChoice(int choice, int count)
{
    if(choice == 1)
    {
        PrintEntry(count);
    }
    else if(choice == 2)
    {
        int x;
        string searchStr;

        cin >> x >> searchStr;

        FindString(count, x, searchStr);
    }
    else if(choice == 3)
    {
        int x;
        float info;
        
        cin >> x >> info;

        FindNumber(x, info);
    }
}

void FindString(int count, int choice, string searchStr)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if(choice == 1)
        {
            if(GalleryOfArt[i].Name == searchStr)
            {
                cout << "String in index: " << i << endl;
            }
        }
        else if(choice == 2)
        {
            if(GalleryOfArt[i].Title == searchStr)
            {
                cout << "String in index: " << i << endl;
            }
        }
        else if(choice == 3)
        {
            if(GalleryOfArt[i].Medium == searchStr)
            {
                cout << "String in index: " << i << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
void FindNumber(int choice, float searchNumber)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < NUMPIECES; i++)
    {
        if(choice == 1)
        {
            if(GalleryOfArt[i].Price == searchNumber)
            {
                cout << "Number in index: " << i << endl;
            }
        }
        else if(choice == 2)
        {
            if(GalleryOfArt[i].Width == searchNumber)
            {
                cout << "Number in index: " << i << endl;
            }
        }
        else if(choice == 3)
        {
            if(GalleryOfArt[i].Height == searchNumber)
            {
                cout << "Number in index: " << i << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Read [tour], [ask], and [example]. As is, your question is too long for me to care.

Comment: When you write code, start with something small and simple that works perfectly, then add complexity a little at a time, testing at every step. *Never add to code that doesn't work.* That way, when a bug appears you'll know where it is, and you won't have to waste time back-tracking. If you write a lot of code without testing any of it, you will find that it's full of mysterious bugs.

Comment: "I have attached a picture"... where? Please, edit your question according to @JohnFilleau 's instructions (above) and the chances for you to get help will be bigger. Good luck.